# Why scrollByLines and scrollByPages not working?

Tags: javascript

I tried to scroll my document with scrollByLines and scrollByPages 
but those are not working but scrollTop and scrollBy working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However if you are a firefox OS app developer you can use it scrollByLines and scrollByPages 
it will work only document with paragraph tag. Now days latest versions of browser implementing

> **browser supports :**
>
> firefox 2 to latest
>       chrome 29

so use the cross-browser scrollBy method instead.